# How to end a thread c# cross thread error

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a simple program that copies files to muliple locations in parallel. I have a form that pops up as a progress bar:

```
public partial class PleaseWait : Form
{
    private static PleaseWait mInstance;
    public static void Create()
    {
        var t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            mInstance = new PleaseWait();
            mInstance.FormClosed += (s, e) => mInstance = null;
            Application.Run(mInstance);
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    public static void Destroy()
    {
        if (mInstance != null) mInstance.Invoke(new Action(() => mInstance.Close()));
    }

    public PleaseWait()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int t = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (t == 100)
        {
            t = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            t = t + 10;
            progressBar1.Value = t;
        }
    }
}
```

I call the `Create` for each copy thread and then destroy once each has completed
9 time out of 10 it will close them all but sometimes I am left one still open so I tried
using this code

```
private void closewait()
{
    foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (f is file_copy.PleaseWait)
        {
            f.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get a cross thread error. How can I make sure that once the copy is complete I don't have any `PleaseWait` forms still open.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Dispose` on the correct thread by using `Control.Invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be called PleaseWait form's method to close & dispose by itself.

And PleaseWait form should be use a flag dected whether to end the timer.

Comment: ok i am new to c# trying to teach myself can you give a example for the flag timer or point me to a resource that i can read up on the flags

Answer (score 0):

It can be due referencing to one mInstance field from multiple threads.

If you want to show only one copy of "Please Wait", you should create reference counter
mRef++ on create form (when mRef > 0 show/create the form), mRef-- on close form (when mRef == 0, hide/close the form).

If you need a multiple "Please Wait", you should create array of thread instances.

In Both cases you shouldn't use thread shared static field.